# Improve performance in linq query - trying to change the query from subquery to join

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am doing the below linq query which is costing me a lot and this query is in a loop which I can not avoid and I have to do it in C# which also I can not avoid. I have lot of logic above the linq query and after the query. I wanted to check if I can change anything on the query to improve the performance at least a little bit.

```
lstDataTable.Where(i => i.Field<int>("ALLL_Snapshot_ID") == 20 && 
i.Field<int>("ALLL_Analysis_Segment_Group_Column_ID") == 5 &&
i.Field<DateTime>("OriginationDate") > startingSnapshotDate &&
i.Field<DateTime>("OriginationDate") <= endingSnapshotDate &&
snapshotDataWithDate.Select(j => j.Field<string>
("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")).Contains(i.Field<string>
("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")) &&
snapshotDataWithDate.Select(j => j.Field<string>
("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")).Contains(i.Field<string>
("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")))
.Select(i => i.Field<Decimal>("BalanceOutstanding") + i.Field<Decimal>
("UndisbursedCommitmentAvailability")).Sum();
```

where lstDataTable and snapshotDataWithDate are IEnumerable of DataRow.

I tried above query using join but it is not joining properly. The difference between the two results is way high. Below is the query I tried using join

```
 (from p in lstDataTable
 join t in snapshotDataWithDate on p.Field<string>
 ("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey") equals t.Field<string>
 ("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey") && 
 p.Field<string>("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey") equals 
 t.Field<string>("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")
 where p.Field<int>("ALLL_Analysis_Segment_Group_Column_ID") == 
 SegmentGroupCECLSurvivalRateObj.ALLL_Segment_Group_Column_ID &&
 p.Field<DateTime>("OriginationDate") > startingSnapshotDate && 
 p.Field<DateTime>("OriginationDate") <= endingSnapshotDate
 select p.Field<Decimal>("BalanceOutstanding") + p.Field<Decimal>
 ("UndisbursedCommitmentAvailability")).Sum();
```

Comment: The join query does not even compile. See [Join by using composite keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys).

Comment: Are you sure that your first query is correct? What do these conditions checks `snapshotDataWithDate.Select(j => j.Field<string>("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")).Contains(i.Field<string>("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey"))` and `snapshotDataWithDate.Select(j => j.Field<string>("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")).Contains(i.Field<string>("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")))`. And in first query you are using Contains in Join - equals.

Comment: Yes the first query is correct but not the second query, if i do join using linq it is getting wrong value

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I have changed some expressions in where clause.

```
lstDataTable.Where(i => i.Field<int>("ALLL_Snapshot_ID") == 20 && 
i.Field<int>("ALLL_Analysis_Segment_Group_Column_ID") == 5 &&
i.Field<DateTime>("OriginationDate") > startingSnapshotDate &&
i.Field<DateTime>("OriginationDate") <= endingSnapshotDate &&
snapshotDataWithDate.Any(j => j.Field<string>
("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey") == i.Field<string>
("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")) &&
snapshotDataWithDate.Any(j => j.Field<string>
("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey") == i.Field<string>
("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")))
.Select(i => i.Field<Decimal>("BalanceOutstanding") + i.Field<Decimal>
("UndisbursedCommitmentAvailability")).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps pulling out the `Field` accesses will provide a small amount of optimization?

```
var snapshotDataConvertedMDB = snapshotDataWithDate.Select(r => r.Field<string>("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")).ToList();

var snapshotDataConvertedODB = snapshotDataWithDate.Select(r => r.Field<string>("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey")).ToList();

var ans = lstDataTable
        .Select(r => new {
            ALLL_Snapshot_ID = r.Field<int>("ALLL_Snapshot_ID"),
            ALLL_Analysis_Segment_Group_Column_ID = r.Field<int>("ALLL_Analysis_Segment_Group_Column_ID"),
            OriginationDate = r.Field<DateTime>("OriginationDate"),
            MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey = r.Field<string>("MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey"),
            OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey = r.Field<string>("OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey"),
            BalanceOutstanding = r.Field<Decimal>("BalanceOutstanding"),
            UndisbursedCommitmentAvailability = r.Field<Decimal>("UndisbursedCommitmentAvailability")
        })
        .Where(i => i.ALLL_Snapshot_ID == 20 &&
                 i.ALLL_Analysis_Segment_Group_Column_ID == 5 &&
                 i.OriginationDate > startingSnapshotDate &&
                 i.OriginationDate <= endingSnapshotDate &&
                 snapshotDataConvertedMDB.Contains(i.MaturityDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey) &&
                 snapshotDataConvertedODB.Contains(i.OriginationDateBorrowerIdNoteNumberKey))
        .Select(i => i.BalanceOutstanding + i.UndisbursedCommitmentAvailability)
        .Sum();
```